# How do I fill automatically a foreign key on a form of multiple pages in Django? (function based view)

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a website where the user have to compile a form to start an equipment purchase procedure. In my django website I've created several models with the Foreign Key referred to the principal model which is called MAIN.

In particular I have these two models: MAIN and SPECIFICATIONS. SPECIFICATIONS has a foreign key which is ID_request and it connects to the MAIN model.

models.py

```
class MAIN(models.Model):
 ## attributes

class SPECIFICATIONS(models.Model):
    ID_request = models.ForeignKey(MAIN, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Spec = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    CliReas = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    rif = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    MinMax = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

I'm structuring the form into two pages, where in the first one the user has to compile some fields of the MAIN model. In the second one I would like to make the user fill 'Spec', 'CliReas', 'rif', 'MinMax' fields, but I want also the ID_request be automatically set to that of the previously entered device.
Can you suggest me how I can do it?

I'm using function-based views:

views.py

```
def new_2_4(request):
    form = SpecForm()

    if request.method=='POST':
        form1 = SpecForm(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            form1.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context={'form1': form1}
    return render(request, 'new_2_4.html', context)
```

And forms.py

```
class SpecForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SPECIFICATIONS
        fields = ['ID_request', 'rif','Spec', 'CliReas', 'MinMax']
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: How the user is going from page1 (main form) to page2 (spec form)? Clicks on the main form submit button and then is redirected to the 2nd page?

Comment: yes, into the function for the first form, I've set return redirect('/new_2_4/')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a query param when you are redirecting users from the main view to the 2nd view.

```py
def main_view(...):
    ...
    main = main_form.save()
    return redirect(f'/spec-view?main_id={main.id}')


def spec_view(...):
    main_id = request.GET.get('main_id')
    return render(request, "spec/template.html", {"main_id":main_id})
```

And set the `main_id` param in `SpecForm` inside the spec template in a hidden field.

Note that this way has some disadvantages like users are able to change the URL manually and try to trick you. You should have some validations or check their sessions in both views to be equal on the same `main_id` or any other ways you know.